# How to mock/ioc a class in a static class?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, moq, rhino-mocks

I have class which calls a static class, the static class basically is wrapper for another class. I know i can't mock/ioc static classes but can do this for the non-static class?

below is a sample of my code structure

```
namespace lib.CanModify
{
    public class Something
    {
        public void method()
        {
            var obj = lib.CanNotModify.StaticClass.DoSomething();


        }
    }

}
namespace lib.CanNotModify
{
    public static class StaticClass
    {
        public static Node DoSomething()
        {
            /*The class i want to mock!*/
            Node node = new Node(10);
            return node;

        }
    }
}
```

please advice a way to mock the node class via mstest

Comment: You can change you class from static to non-static? Otherwise you cannot mock, If node is Field, not local parameter, you can mock

Comment: That method looks pure to me. IMO you should not mock side effect free code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the short answer is no!

You cannot mock concrete implementations of classes. You can only create instances of classes, you can only mock interfaces or base classes. A mock pretends to be a concrete class by implementing the properties of the interface or base class using inheritance. basically creating a new concrete instance of the class on the fly.

If you change your structure to:

```
public class Node() : INode
```

Then you could mock this:

```
var moqNode = new Mock<INode>();
```

*(this is moq syntax btw)*

you would then need to change your variable to type `INode`

```
INode node = new Node(10);
```

and then you'd actually also need to inject your dependancy:

```
public static Node DoSomething(INode node)
        {

            return node;

        }
```

which would make a farce of the entire thing......?!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `StaticClassWrapper` and an interface `IStaticClass`, then inject `IStaticClass` into your method.

Then you can easily mock `IStaticClass`

```
namespace lib.CanModify
{
    using lib.CanNotModify;

    public class Something
    {
        public void method()
        {
            method(new StaticClassWrapper());
        }

        public void method(IStaticClass staticClass)
        {
            var obj = staticClass.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public interface IStaticClass
    {
        Node DoSomething();
    }

    public class StaticClassWrapper : IStaticClass
    {
        public Node DoSomething()
        {
            return lib.CanNotModify.StaticClass.DoSomething();
        }
    }

}
```

This is similar to how the ASP.NET MVC project made classes such as `System.Web.HttpRequest` mockable